# how do set input type date default value today in .net

Tags: c#, html, .net

How can i set default value today

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
    <label for="start">Günün Menüsü için Tarih Seçiniz:</label>

    <input type="date" runat="server" id="datee" name="trip-start"
           value=""
           min="2021-01-01" max="2022-12-31">

</div>
```

and i dont wanna like this
[image]

i wanna like this example today = 29.03.2021

Answer (score 0):

for **.net** you can add `@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` in value, Please replace below code and check.

```
<input type="date" runat="server" id="datee" name="trip-start"
       value='@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")'
       min="2021-01-01" max="2022-12-31">
```

Comment: i'm sorry but not working just saying `gg.aa.yyyy`

Comment: Please try to use date picker instead of input type date,  and set localize as per your time zone.
I think this will solve you issue.